# Using spacy and NLP to relate pronouns to their respective nouns

Tags: python, nlp, spacy

I would like to write a code that can identify pronouns and relate them to their respective nouns in the sentence or previous sentence. For example, let say I have the following sentence: "John and Maggie walk along the street. He told her he is leaving for Paris. She was surprised"
I want to get a result like: He refers to John, She refers to Maggie.

the code I am writing is as follows:

```
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_md")


text = "John and Maggie walk along the street. He told her he is leaving for Paris. She was surprised"
doc = nlp(text)


pronoun = ""
antecedent = ""

for token in doc:
    if token.dep_ in ("nsubj", "nsubjpass"):
        if token.head.dep_ == "ccomp":
        
            antecedent = token.head.head.text
        else:
            antecedent = token.text
    elif token.dep_ == "dobj" and token.head.dep_ == "ccomp":
        
        antecedent = token.head.head.text

  
    if token.pos_ == "PRON" and antecedent:
        pronoun = token.text
        print(f"{pronoun} refers to {antecedent}")
        antecedent = ""
```

what i am getting is the following:

```
He refers to He
he refers to told
She refers to She
```

Not sure what I am doing wrong. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: "He told her that he is leaving *for* Paris", if he's going to Paris.

Comment: Honestly I don't think spaCy is capable of identifying the subjects to which every pronoun belong. They never demonstrate this in their [linguistic features](https://spacy.io/usage/linguistic-features/) dependency parser. And if you think about it, such would require a memory of the whole context of the text because sometimes the subject of a pronoun in a sentence is named several sentences before or after the given sentence. It can get incredibly complex tracking that and can confuse even the best of us humans.

Comment: @molbdnilo this isn't [english stackexchange](https://english.stackexchange.com/) ;)

Comment: I only need to have it recognize the nouns one or two sentences back at most. I can refer to the most recent identification (e.g., he: John, she: Maggie) in the case of longer history, if needed.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are describing is called coreference resolution:
*the most common use cases in English are resolving the referents of pronouns to noun phrases.*

Here is a nice blogpost by the spaCy people on how to do it:
https://explosion.ai/blog/coref

Also, there is a package you can use in spaCy:
https://spacy.io/universe/project/neuralcoref

Comment: Thanks for the info. This is exactly what i am looking for.